MAUI save image in Resources/Images folder
I am relatively new to the MAUI world and am creating a test app for practice.
It consists of a warehouse with a list of foods, each of which is editable and has its own photo.
I integrate the app with DevExpress for MAUI, and I am able to upload and output an image but not save it.
The test records I create retrieve the image from Resources/Images, but when I change the image I can't save the new file in the same folder so that it is associated with my record.
Can you help me or tell me where to find specific documentation ?I hope I am clear,
thanks to all for the help.

The static files in the resources folder are read-only. You can choose to use the device local storage to save the image.

Once the build is prepared, the resource images are set to read-only. It is recommended to store them in the mobile phone storage. You can create a folder in the mobile app and perform all necessary operations there. For information on storage location, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android. Please be aware that there may be different permission requirements based on the platform, so it is advisable to consult the documentation before proceeding with the implementation. Hope this will help you.
